# Change the default accounting format in excel

Tags: excel, format, default, accounting

In latest version of excel the default accounting format (Home > Number) is dollars, in the dropdown you get the GBP sign but i cant find anyway to change it to the default button.  I have checked every language setting i can find on the PC and in office and they are all set to UK or English (not USA)

Any ideas!

[Image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Usq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the drop down near $ sign and click more accounting formats

select the GBP Symbol UK as per image

[image: GBP selection]

Comment: Thanks, that only changes the selected cell
I want to change the default button on the home tab

Comment: if you need to change the default. then go to control panel search Currency. Click Change the way currency is displayed. https://blog.cometdocs.com/guide-to-working-with-currencies-in-excel#:~:text=However%2C%20if%20you%20need%20to,can%20significantly%20save%20your%20time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default settings in Excel because the default settings are defined by the system. On Windows 11, this is how you do it:

You need to go to Settings -> Time & Language -> Language & Region. Then click on the button "[Administrative language settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9H9L.png)".

This opens up a [control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o30CU.png) called "Region". Go to its "Formats" tab and select "Additional settings...". There you can adjust the [default formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0rey.png) for numbers, currency, time and dates!